# How to maximise Screen use in Pupeteer ( non-headless )

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm testing out puppeteer for chrome browser automation 
( previously using selenium but had a few headaches with browser not waiting until page fully loaded ) .

When I launch an instance of puppeteer - then it displays the contents taking up less than half the screen with scroll bars.  How can I make it take up a full screen?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function test(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
      });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://google.com')
}

test()
```

The initial page seems to load fine , but as soon as I access a page it makes it scrollable and smaller.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You probably would want to set a certain screen size, which any real browser has:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768});
  await page.goto('https://example.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: setViewport not worked for me, but given below code work const browser = await puppeteer.launch( {"headless": false, args: ['--start-maximized'] } );

Answer (score 55):

you can user options in launch

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args:[
       '--start-maximized' // you can also use '--start-fullscreen'
    ]
    });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768});
  await page.goto('https://example.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: I tHink it's browser version dependent. Works on chrome 62 when I tried

Answer (score 48):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
  });

  const pages = await browser.pages();
  const page = pages[0];
  await page.goto('https://google.com');
})();
```

Source:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3688#issuecomment-453218745

Comment: Great answer and thanks for linking the source!

Comment: much cleaner this way than declaring it on its own, thanks!

Comment: This is the coolest and neatest answer. Solved the problem directly.

Answer (score 25):

Code snippet with related properties

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
    {
      headless: false, //defaults to true 
      defaultViewport: null, //Defaults to an 800x600 viewport
      executablePath: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe', 
                     //by default puppeteer runs Chromium buddled with puppeteer 
      args:['--start-maximized' ]
    });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');

})();
```

Comment: This is a very accurate answer. It fits the size to default viewport

Answer (score 9):

for full screen, i do this:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 0, height: 0});
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: does not work for me when connecting to an existing browser

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Puppeteer Documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api/puppeteer.page.setviewport.md):

> ###page.setViewport(viewport)
>
> - `viewport` <[Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)>
> - `width` <[number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type)> page width in pixels.
> - `height` <[number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type)> page height in pixels.
> - `deviceScaleFactor` <[number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type)> Specify device scale factor (can be thought of as dpr). Defaults to `1`.
> - `isMobile` <[boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Boolean_type)> Whether the `meta viewport` tag is taken into account. Defaults to `false`.
> - `hasTouch` <[boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Boolean_type)> Specifies if viewport supports touch events. Defaults to `false`
> - `isLandscape` <[boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Boolean_type)> Specifies if viewport is in landscape mode. Defaults to `false`.
> - returns: <[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)>
>
> > **NOTE** in certain cases, setting viewport will reload the page in order to set the `isMobile` or `hasTouch` properties.
>
> In the case of multiple pages in a single browser, each page can have its own viewport size.

Therefore, you can use [`page.setViewport()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api/puppeteer.page.setviewport.md) to set the page width and height:

```
await page.setViewport({
  width: 1366,
  height: 768,
});
```

> **Note:** Make sure to use the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) operator when calling [`page.setViewport()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api/puppeteer.page.setviewport.md), as the function is asynchronous.

Comment: This sets the page viewport not the browser size