# Set pupeteer window size when running not headless (not viewport)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, typescript, testing, puppeteer

Is it somehow possible to set the browsers (Chrome[ium]) window size like the viewport size?

Setting only the viewport results in a unhandy appearance when the browser is not running headfully and I want to visually see what's going on within the browser instance.

So I would like something like below:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false, // The browser is visible
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
}),
page = await browser.newPage();


// This is well explained in the API
await page.setViewport({
    width: options.width,
    height: options.height
});

// But is there something like this (careful this is dummy code)
browser.setWindowSize({
    width: options.width,
    height: options.height
});
```

Thanks for any help pointing me into the right direction

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How to maximise Screen use in Pupeteer ( non-headless )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48013969/how-to-maximise-screen-use-in-pupeteer-non-headless)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can set chrome window size during `puppeteer.launch` with flag [`--window-size`](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#window-size)

Here is usage in your example:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false, // The browser is visible
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    args: [`--window-size=${options.width},${options.height}`] // new option
});
```

Answer (score 41):

This resizes the window and the view area

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      args: [`--window-size=1920,1080`],
      defaultViewport: {
        width:1920,
        height:1080
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want it to behave like a normal browser where it resizes the viewport to the window size. Then set the viewport to null

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
{
    defaultViewport: null,
    headless: false
});
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: `defaultViewport: null`
This works, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null,
        args: ['--start-maximized'], // we can use '--start-fullscreen' || --start-maximized
    });
```